# Tooltip is not hiding, if we disabled the button on click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip, popper.js, jquery-ui-tooltip

Tooltip is not hiding, if we disabled the button on click

```
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

here is an running example.
https://jsfiddle.net/JitanGupta/e8fjd0nL/

I am using basic setup with bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `hide` or `show` :

```
        $("#btn").on("click", function () {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
             $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
        });
```

Comment: Thank you @Frenchy for the solution. This is a workaround and I have done the same, but still solution is not justifiable to me. I think this is a issue with plugin itself.

Comment: In general, disabled elements do not trigger any DOM events. Therefore, it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, either you play with hide or play with opacity, but you dont have other solution

Answer (score 1):

Just use single line of code for hiding any element tooltip after click.

```
$(document).on("click","*[data-toggle='tooltip']",function(){$(this).tooltip('hide');});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is

```js
$("[role='tooltip']").remove()
```

Removes any tooltip on the page